# How to add 2 lines at the start of all the .c files in the directory using shell or perl

Tags: perl, shell, sed

I have lots of .c files and .h files in a directory. I need to add a comment at the start of all the .c like "// INFO: THis is C Files written by raj". Can you please tell how to do this with the script?.

Comment: This sort of low-level, platform agnostic, byte shifting is why I've settled on .NET to write my boilerplate for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a one-shot task so an easy approach is to do something like this:

```
for x in *.c *.h; do
    echo "//INFO This is C Files written by raj" > $x.temp-file
    cat $x >> $x.temp-file
    mv $x.temp-file $x
done
```

Of course, make sure you backup your files first.

Comment: The SSD is in my lazy bones tells me this could be done better with RAM buffers. Linux has such nice RAM disks I'm almost tempted to use it day-day.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
find cpath-to-find -type f -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -execdir \
 sed '1i\//INFO This is C Files written by raj' {} \+
```

With `awk`:

```
find cpath-to-find -type f -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -execdir \
awk ' NR == 1 { print "//INFO This is C Files written by raj"; } {print;}'
```

Comment: This is basically the correct approach, but you have missing quotes in the `find` command, and your `sed` script is a bit of a mess. There is a dedicated `sed` command `i` for inserting a line - I would definitely prefer that.

Comment: @Raj: find all *.c and *.h files in the path `cpath-to-find` and apply the command

Answer (score 2):

Quick one-liner:

```
perl -pi -we 'local $/; s#^#//comment\n#;' *.c *.h
```

Explanation:

- Using in-place edit with `-pi` (if you want backups: `-i<extension>`,
  e.g. `-i.bak`).
- Use slurp mode (read whole file by setting `$/` to undef) to only
  affect first line.
- Use a shell glob to find the files.